# How to programmatically avoid loading, not just rendering, of web page based on display size

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design

I have a set of web pages that are about 1MB each in size. My task is to download only a subset of the content of the page if the display is smaller than a desktop display. Note that I need to actually abort the load, not just abort the rendering. I don't believe window.stop() would do the trick, plus it's not supported in IE. The aim is to save mobile users from using up data bandwidth.

I can accomplish what I want by having a separate mobile site but it's my preference to avoid that if possible and to do this task via a single responsive site.

Is there a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do this all wrong. You shouldn't abort existing loading - that's wrong approach. You simply should fix your site and make it load only that content it is going to show.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I know the obvious solution. I need to do some due diligence before I proceed with the obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small, landing script that looks at the device dimensions and goes off to get the appropriate file.

Serve that file by default.

Comment: I may need to do that but it doesn't meet my customer's requirements.